# How to find response of step function in matlab and plot transfer function?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, control-systems, step-response

I have an transfer function:
$$\frac{Y(s)}{F(s)} = \frac{s^2+2s+3}{s^4+6s^3+13s^2+12s+9}$$

How can I find $Y(s)$ response of step function if $f(t)=\sin(5t)$ in MATLAB. And how can I plot the transfer function?

Comment: Hi! This looks like a HomeWork... You must provide solution steps, and tell where you are confused about, to get a meaningful response...

Comment: I have converted your math to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (edit may be pending).  Please check to see if I did so correctly and consider using MathJax in the future.